# Нужно ли удалять объект строки полученный при помощи String::Format?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, сборщик-мусора

Во время отладки, я делаю форматирование строки для передачи в `Trace::WriteLine`.

`String::Format` отдает строку не по значению, а по ссылке `System::String^`.

Нужно ли удалять эту строку при помощи оператора `delete`, или оставить ее на съедение `GC`?

Comment: `System::String^` - управляемый тип. Вручную удалять не нужно. GC сам удалит.

Comment: Все типы со значком `^` - управляемые. За ними следит GC. А вот типы со значком `*` - неуправляемые, нативные. Их нужно удалять вручную (или оборачивать в умные указатели).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, почему не ответом?

Answer (score 2):

`System::String^` - управляемый тип. Вручную удалять не нужно. GC сам удалит.

В C++/CLI все типы со значком `^` - управляемые. За ними следит GC. А вот типы со значком `*` - неуправляемые, нативные. Их нужно удалять вручную (или оборачивать в умные указатели).

Оператор `delete`, применённый к управляемому типу, не удаляет объект. Он вызывает метод `Dispose`. Так как `System::String^` не является disposable типом, то применять к нему `delete` нет смысла.

Comment: Вопрос не об этом. а о том, нужно ли, если оно не требуется далее по контексту.

Comment: @ヒミコ подойдем с другой стороны: а как вы это вообще сделаете?